# How can I upload all the form data at once to firebase in react-native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

The error I'm facing while sending my form data **Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.**

```
export default class AddShipment extends React.Component{
  state={
    Courier_trackerId: "",
    Courier_ShipperName: "",
    Courier_PhoneNum: "",
    Courier_Address: ""
  }
  InputTextField=(props)=> {
    return (
        <View style={props.style}>
            <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>{props.title}</Text>
            <TextInput
                placeholder={props.placeholderText}
                secureTextEntry={props.isSecure}
                style={styles.input}
                onChangeText={
                  text=>{this.setState({ 'props.var' : text })}
                }
            />
            <View style={{ borderBottomColor: "#D8D8D8", borderBottomWidth: 1 }} />
        </View>
    );
  }

  addNewShipment= async()=>{
    firestore().collection("Couriers").add({
      TrackerId : this.state.Courier_trackerId,
      ShipperName : this.state.Courier_ShipperName,
      PhoneNum : this.state.Courier_PhoneNum,
      Address : this.state.Courier_Address
    })
  }
  render()
  {
    return(
      <ScrollView style={{backgroundColor:"#FFF", height: "100%", flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 30}}>
        <Text style={[styles.text, { marginTop: 10, fontSize: 22, fontWeight: "500", alignSelf:'center' }]}>Add New Shipment</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.text, { color: "#ABB4BD", fontSize: 15, textAlign: "center", marginVertical: 20 }]}>Fill in the details </Text>
        <this.InputTextField 
        style={{marginTop: 25, marginBottom: 8}}
        title="Tracking-ID"
        var="Courier_trackerId" />
        <this.InputTextField 
        style={{marginTop: 25, marginBottom: 8}}
        title="Shipper Name"
        var="Courier_ShipperName" />
        <this.InputTextField 
        style={{marginTop: 25, marginBottom: 8}}
        title="Phone Number"
        var="Courier_PhoneNum" />
        <this.InputTextField 
        style={{marginTop: 25, marginBottom: 8}}
        title="Address"
        var="Courier_Address" />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitContainer} onPress={this.addNewShipment}>
                        <Text
                            style={[
                                styles.text,
                                {
                                    color: "#FFF",
                                    fontWeight: "600",
                                    fontSize: 16
                                }
                            ]}
                        >
                            Add Shipment
                        </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}
```

If there is any way to modify this existing function it will be much better than to make a complete new function as I am using `InputTextField` on multiple screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be solved once you fix some typos in your code.

Taking a look at these lines:

```js
addNewShipment= async()=>{
  firestore().collection("Couriers").add({
    TrackerId : this.state.Courier_trackerId,
    ShipperName : this.state.Courier_ShipperName,
    PhoneNum : this.state.Courier_PhoneNum,
    Address : this.state.Courier_Address
  })
}
```

Here, you intend to do some asynchronous work that takes some time to resolve, however, your add operation here is "floating". It is not used with `await` nor is it returned as the result of the function. This leads to `addNewShipment` starting the add data to database call, but not waiting for it's result. Adding `async` to the function definition is not enough on it's own.

To correct this, you would do either of the following:

```js
addNewShipment = async () => {
  // ⮟ will return the Promise<DocumentReference> from add()
  return firestore().collection("Couriers").add({
    TrackerId : this.state.Courier_trackerId,
    ShipperName : this.state.Courier_ShipperName,
    PhoneNum : this.state.Courier_PhoneNum,
    Address : this.state.Courier_Address
  })
}

// addNewShipment is a () => Promise<DocumentReference>
```

or

```js
addNewShipment = async () => {
  await firestore().collection("Couriers").add({
    TrackerId : this.state.Courier_trackerId,
    ShipperName : this.state.Courier_ShipperName,
    PhoneNum : this.state.Courier_PhoneNum,
    Address : this.state.Courier_Address
  })
}

// addNewShipment is a () => Promise<void>
```

You could use `return await firestore().coll...` but that's just inefficient in this scenario.

Next, we need to take a look at these lines:

```js
return (
    <View style={props.style}>
        <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>{props.title}</Text>
        <TextInput
            placeholder={props.placeholderText}
            secureTextEntry={props.isSecure}
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={
              text=>{this.setState({ 'props.var' : text })}
            }
        />
        <View style={{ borderBottomColor: "#D8D8D8", borderBottomWidth: 1 }} />
    </View>
);
```

Here, you are trying to assign to the state based on the value of `props.var` such as `this.setState({ Courier_PhoneNum: text })`, however, the text `props.var` isn't getting evaluated and instead sets `this.state['props.var'] = text` instead of `this.state.Courier_PhoneNum = text`.

This is corrected by using square brackets in the object assignment:

```js
// consider throwing an error if `props.var` is not set.
return (
    <View style={props.style}>
        <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>{props.title}</Text>
        <TextInput
            placeholder={props.placeholderText}
            secureTextEntry={props.isSecure}
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={
              text=>{this.setState({ [props.var] : text })}
            }
        />
        <View style={{ borderBottomColor: "#D8D8D8", borderBottomWidth: 1 }} />
    </View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For issue: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component,
you can create a function like `updateMyState=(state)=>{}` which further setState to update state, Based on a particular check.
It will update only if the component is mounted, If component unMount then it doesn't update the state.

P.S. I think that issue is not linked with firebase.